# How to create a single xml file from multiple XSDs

Tags: xml, xsd, schema

I have a huge xsd(schema) file, which I would call XSD1. XSD1 includes 7 other XSDs using xs:include. I would like to know if there is a tool or any website using which I can create a single xml file(a sample XML) based on XSD1 and other 7 XSDs?

Comment: @kjhughes: I have tried using OxygenXML Editor to achieve my requirement. But, it doesn't create a valid xml when there are multiple XSDs are to be considered. Will try the XMLAssist and QTAssistant.

Comment: Surprised to hear that about oXygen XML Editor.   Are you sure the XSDs were valid prior to the flattening?  A [mcve] showing a valid *before* and an invalid *after* for the XSD flattening operation would make a good separate question (not to mention a good bug report to Syncro Soft).